# How to create a table from the results of a SQL query?

Tags: sql, database

How can I put the results of a query into a table which is NOT created?

For example, put the following query results into a new table `EmployeeDetail` which IS NOT CREATED. Create the table and put the results at the same time.

```
select a.Name, b.Id
from Database1 a left join 
     Database2 b
ON a.Id = b.Id
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify your RDBMS system, but in SQL Server it would be like this

```
select a.Name, b.Id into EmployeeDetail 
from Database1 a left join Database2 b ON a.Id = b.Id
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

CREATE TABLE table_name
AS ...

where the ... is your query.

Here is a link with more documentation: http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/sql-createtableas.html

Comment: +1: This is supported on [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), and [Oracle](http://www.comp.dit.ie/btierney/oracle11gdoc/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm) too

Answer (score 2):

This will be RDBMS dependant. If you are using SQL Server you can use `SELECT ... INTO`

```
select a.Name, b.Id
into EmployeeDetail 
 from Database1 a left join Database2 b ON a.Id = b.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle SQL*Plus, the following syntax is used

```
CREATE TABLE <table name> AS <your query>;
```

For example,

```
CREATE TABLE managers AS SELECT * FROM employees WHERE desg = 'MANAGER';
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT [INTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx)

```
SELECT a.Name, b.id
INTO newTable
FROM from Database1 a 
LEFT JOIN Database2 b
```

Answer (score -1):

Send the create table command before the sql to insert the rows.