# SQL query results into a table

Tags: sql

I wanna put the results from sql query into a table but if i do SELECT columns names INTO NEWTABLE(which is not created), its good for one time but when i run that query again, it says table already exists. All i am doing is results from that query into the newtable and i am gonna run it every week so it should not give me the error: table already exists.

For Example : i wanna put Following query results into a Newtable EmployeeDetails and i am gonna run it every week.

```
select a.Name, b.Id 
from Database1 a left join  
     Database2 b 
ON a.Id = b.Id
```

Comment: You only want the script to make a new table once? Then every week simply add data on the existing one?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to create a table from the results of a SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534735/how-to-create-a-table-from-the-results-of-a-sql-query)

Comment: @OMG: not quite, a bit different scenario

Comment: Also, what are you using? SQL Server? MySQL ?

Comment: @Eton B.: Only difference I can see is the table has to be temporary now, and still no clarification on the database.

Comment: COMMENT:  You don't have to tell us you are asking a question in the title of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with IF EXISTS

example for sql server

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[YOurTableName]') 
AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
      DROP TABLE [dbo].[YOurTableName
END

select * into [dbo].[YOurTableName]
from ......
```

Answer (score 3):

Use INSERT INTO instead.

But make sure that the table is already created before you call insert into the first time,

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, ...)
SELECT column3, column4, ...
FROM table2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[YOurTableName]') AND type in (N'U')) 
      //INSERT INTO STATEMENT
ELSE
     //SELECT INTO STATEMENT THAT U ALREADY HAVE
```

Answer (score 0):

use insert - 
insert into newtbl select x,y,z from tbl

(make sure you create the table first)

Comment: i tried that but table name is gonna be the same so it gives me the same error : table already exists

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the generated table for the duration of the current SQL connection, create a temporary table:

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE newtable SELECT the_rest_of_your_query`

Or, if you want to keep the table around for a week, but replace it completely each week, make sure it's gone first:

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newtable`